# Read Floating Point Numbers from string in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, text-files, string-comparison

I'm new to Matlab and I'm trying to read data (x,y coordinates) from a text file in Matlab and store in a 2D array. My goal is to look through a text file in the following format:

```
XPos 4180
YPos 60
Orientation 98.69
AccelX 438.00
AccelY 161.00
AccelZ -865.00
XPos 4079
YPos -379
```

I am able to check if the line contains 'XPos', but i'm not able to retrieve the number on the same line and store it in the empty array that I've initialized. I have tried using sscanf and regex. I have commented the regular expression line out, but it does work. However it stores the value in a cell array, but again, I've ran into problems trying to retrieve the value from the cell array and store it in my empty 2D array.

```
dataPoints = zeros(n,n);
row = 0;
column = 0;

file = fopen('file.txt', 'r');

while ~feof(file)
    line = fgets(file);
    fprintf(line);

    k = strfind(line, 'XPos');

    if(isempty(k))

    else
        fprintf('Found One');
        %x = regexp(line, '.*?(\d+(\.\d+)*)', 'tokens' );
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `textscan`. for example :

```
fid = fopen(s);
C = textscan(fid,'%s %f');
fclose(fid);

array2D = [C{2}(strcmp(C{1},'XPos')),C{2}(strcmp(C{1},'YPos'))]
```

But I'm not quite sure of what you want as an output.

Comment: Probably `array2D = [C{2}(strcmp(C{1},'XPos')),C{2}(strcmp(C{1},'YPos'))]`

Comment: Thanks. You guys are awesome.

Comment: Edited following Jon comment

Answer (score 0):

A simple sscanf also works, once you detect the string XPos in the line, the command:
c = sscanf('XPos 4180','XPos %f') 
returns number 4180.